# ImportError: cannot import name 'sun' from 'suntime'

Tags: python

Estoy tratando de instalar suntime con pip3 install suntime en la terminal, pero cuando corro este script en la terminal:

```
import suntime
from suntime import sun, SunTimeException
```

me sale:

```
 File "prueba_suntime.py", line 1, in <module>
    import suntime
  File "C:\Users\Hola\Documents\programas_tesis\pruebas\suntime.py", line 3, in <module>
    from suntime import sun, SunTimeException
ImportError: cannot import name 'sun' from 'suntime'
```

Comment: Según la documentación es `Sun` capitalizado, es decir `from suntime import Sun, SunTimeException`

Comment: Sale lo mismo SunTimeException

Comment: Intenta cambiando el nombre de tu script de "suntime.py" a uno diferente, tal vez entran en conflicto.

Comment: @Rocker ¿has podido solucionar?

Comment: @Adrian Si, muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

¿Podría ser por dónde tengas apuntando la ruta (PATH) de cada uno? Podrías verlo con el siguiente comando en la terminal (linux):

```
$ -> for i in pip pip3 python python3 ; do type $i ; done
```

Tal y como lo tengo en un venv tuve que instalarlo con `pip install suntime`, aunque si tienes pip3 deberías poder usarlo `pip3 install suntime` ( [Suntime Doc](https://pypi.org/project/suntime/) )

**Código**:

```
import datetime
from suntime import Sun, SunTimeException

latitud = 43.36
longitud = -8.41

sun = Sun(latitud, longitud)

hoy_sr = sun.get_sunrise_time()
hoy_ss = sun.get_sunset_time()

print('Hoy el sol en Galicia salió a las {} y baja a las {}'.
      format(hoy_sr.strftime('%H:%M'), hoy_ss.strftime('%H:%M')))
```

**Resultado**

```
(~/stack/python/suntime)$ -> python3 suntime_test.py 
Hoy el sol en Galicia salió a las 06:03 y baja a las 19:01
```